# Calculate sum of guests and count of nights from a duration of stay per year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL data from guests in hotels with different pricing zones with their arrival and departure dates and I want to calculate the number of nights the guest stays in the hotel and also how many guests per month were there. All separated by pricing zone.

Here is my sample dataset

```
ID  From    To  Zone
1   2023-10-01 00:00:00.000 2023-10-06 00:00:00.000 1
2   2023-10-03 00:00:00.000 2023-10-05 00:00:00.000 1
3   2023-09-30 00:00:00.000 2023-10-01 00:00:00.000 2
4   2023-04-14 00:00:00.000 2023-04-20 00:00:00.000 2
5   2023-09-25 00:00:00.000 2023-10-11 00:00:00.000 3
6   2023-08-31 00:00:00.000 2023-09-01 00:00:00.000 1
```

[What I already have is the following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJJj.png)

```
Year    Zone    M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9  M10 M11 M12
2023    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   7   0   0
2023    2   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
2023    3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   11  0   0
```

But I also want to include the number of guests in this result.

If for example the stay was from 2023-09-30 to 2023-10-02, these are two nights and a night always count to the next day. So the night from 30th September to 1st October should count to the values of October. Also the number of guests in October should then be +1.

If for example the stay is from 2023-09-28 to 2023-10-02 then there should be +2 nights in September and +1 guest in September, but also +2 nights in October and +1 guest in October.

The result should then look like this:

```
Year    Zone    M1  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9  M10 M11 M12 G1  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6  G7  G8  G9  G10 G11 G12
2023    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   0   0
2023    2   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
2023    3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
```

How can this be done (I'm using MS SQL Server 2019)?

Here are my sql statements so far:

```
DECLARE @Nights TABLE 
    ([ID] int,[From] datetime, [To] datetime, [Zone] INT)
;

INSERT INTO @Nights
    ([ID], [From], [To], [Zone])
VALUES
    (1, '2023-10-01', '2023-10-06', 1),
    (2, '2023-10-03', '2023-10-05', 1),
    (3, '2023-09-30', '2023-10-01', 2),
    (4, '2023-04-14', '2023-04-20', 2),
    (5, '2023-09-25', '2023-10-11', 3),
    (6, '2023-08-31', '2023-09-01', 1)
;

WITH cteTally as (
    SELECT  MAX(DATEDIFF(day,[From],[To])) - 1 as Tally
    FROM
       @Nights

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Tally - 1
    FROM
       cteTally
    WHERE
       Tally - 1 >= 0
)
, cteDates AS (
    SELECT 
       DATEADD(day,c.Tally+1,t.[From]) as date
       ,YEAR(DATEADD(day,c.Tally+1,t.[From])) as [Year]
       ,'M'+CAST(DATEPART(month,DATEADD(day,c.Tally+1,t.[From])) as varchar(2)) as [Month],t.Zone
--     ,case when c.Tally=0 then 1 else case when DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(day,c.Tally+1,t.[From]))=1 then 1 else 0 end end as Guests,t.[ID]
    FROM
       @Nights t
       INNER JOIN cteTally c
       ON DATEDIFF(day,[From],[To]) - 1 >= c.Tally
       
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cteDates
PIVOT (
       COUNT([date])
       for [Month] IN ([M1],[M2],[M3],[M4],[M5],[M6],[M7],[M8],[M9],[M10],[M11],[M12])
    ) p 
order by [Year],[Zone]
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

If you include the marked out line

```
,case when c.Tally=0 then 1 else case when DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(day,c.Tally+1,t.[From]))=1 then 1 else 0 end end as Guests,t.[ID]
```

and only execute the SQL till *SELECT * FROM cteDates* you can see that a Guest counter will be filled like I need them (for clarification I included an ID for each guest), but I still do not know how to change the PIVOT so that the guests and nights are summed up.

This is the result till *SELECT * FROM cteDates*:

```
date    Year    Month   Zone    Guests  ID
2023-10-02 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 1   1   1
2023-10-03 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 1   0   1
2023-10-04 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 1   0   1
2023-10-05 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 1   0   1
2023-10-06 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 1   0   1
2023-10-04 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 1   1   2
2023-10-05 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 1   0   2
2023-10-01 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 2   1   3
2023-04-15 00:00:00.000 2023    M4  2   1   4
2023-04-16 00:00:00.000 2023    M4  2   0   4
2023-04-17 00:00:00.000 2023    M4  2   0   4
2023-04-18 00:00:00.000 2023    M4  2   0   4
2023-04-19 00:00:00.000 2023    M4  2   0   4
2023-04-20 00:00:00.000 2023    M4  2   0   4
2023-09-26 00:00:00.000 2023    M9  3   1   5
2023-09-27 00:00:00.000 2023    M9  3   0   5
2023-09-28 00:00:00.000 2023    M9  3   0   5
2023-09-29 00:00:00.000 2023    M9  3   0   5
2023-09-30 00:00:00.000 2023    M9  3   0   5
2023-10-01 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   1   5
2023-10-02 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   0   5
2023-10-03 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   0   5
2023-10-04 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   0   5
2023-10-05 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   0   5
2023-10-06 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   0   5
2023-10-07 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   0   5
2023-10-08 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   0   5
2023-10-09 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   0   5
2023-10-10 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   0   5
2023-10-11 00:00:00.000 2023    M10 3   0   5
2023-09-01 00:00:00.000 2023    M9  1   1   6
```

Comment: Don't use images, use tabular text

Comment: `I also want to include the number of guests in this result`. Please show how the result will looks like

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your existing by useing two additional CTEs (cteDates and cteFinal) to calculate the number of guests and then pivots the results as required:

```
DECLARE @Nights TABLE ([ID] int, [From] datetime, [To] datetime, [Zone] INT);

INSERT INTO @Nights
VALUES
    (1, '2023-10-01', '2023-10-06', 1),
    (2, '2023-10-03', '2023-10-05', 1),
    (3, '2023-09-30', '2023-10-01', 2),
    (4, '2023-04-14', '2023-04-20', 2),
    (5, '2023-09-25', '2023-10-11', 3),
    (6, '2023-08-31', '2023-09-01', 1);

WITH cteTally AS (
    SELECT
        MAX(DATEDIFF(day, [From], [To])) - 1 AS Tally
    FROM @Nights

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Tally - 1
    FROM cteTally
    WHERE Tally - 1 >= 0
),
cteDates AS (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(day, c.Tally + 1, t.[From]) AS date,
        YEAR(DATEADD(day, c.Tally + 1, t.[From])) AS [Year],
        'M' + CAST(DATEPART(month, DATEADD(day, c.Tally + 1, t.[From])) AS varchar(2)) AS [Month],
        t.Zone,
        1 AS Guests,
        t.[ID]
    FROM @Nights t
    INNER JOIN cteTally c ON DATEDIFF(day, [From], [To]) - 1 >= c.Tally
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(day, 1, t.[To]) AS date,
        YEAR(DATEADD(day, 1, t.[To])) AS [Year],
        'M' + CAST(DATEPART(month, DATEADD(day, 1, t.[To])) AS varchar(2)) AS [Month],
        t.Zone,
        -1 AS Guests,
        t.[ID]
    FROM @Nights t
),
cteFinal AS (
    SELECT
        [Year],
        Zone,
        [Month],
        SUM(Guests) AS TotalGuests,
        COUNT(date) AS Nights
    FROM cteDates
    GROUP BY [Year], Zone, [Month]
)
SELECT *
FROM cteFinal
PIVOT (
    SUM(Nights) FOR [Month] IN ([M1],[M2],[M3],[M4],[M5],[M6],[M7],[M8],[M9],[M10],[M11],[M12])
) p;
```

Comment: I tried this but neither the number of nights nor the number of guests is correct. Also the number of guests is not splitted by months.